# File Upload Not Working with FileParameter - RestSharp

Tags: c#, file-upload, multipartform-data, restsharp

I am using RestSharp for APIs in my client project.

```
Request.AddParameter(new Parameter("Topic", Topic, ParameterType.GetOrPost));
Request.AddParameter(new Parameter("Details", Details, ParameterType.GetOrPost));                
Request.AddParameter(new Parameter($"UploadedDescription_0", "UploadDescriptions", ParameterType.GetOrPost));
Request.AddFile($"UploadedFile_0", File.ReadAllBytes(filePath), fileName, MimeTypesMap.GetMimeType(fileName));

Request.AlwaysMultipartFormData = true;
```

As you can see from the above code I have added file parameter along with additional fields for an API.

The problem with RestSharp usage

When I send the request without the file description and file parameter, the API works fine. But if I add file parameters, I am getting an error saying the file parameter (the uploaded file) couldn't be validated with the request data.

I have tried a pure HTTP sample code for the same task. The same file with the same parameters works well without any issues. You can refer a similar code [here](https://gist.github.com/jeancroy/c71f8a710734a7d13248f968c778d428#file-multipartupload-cs-L15)

FYI,
I am not adding any additional headers of my own.
The file existence is checked for each file before the call.

I am using the latest version of RestSharp. Can anybody tell me what wrong I am doing here?

Comment: What's the error, exactly? Stacktrace?

Comment: The server is invalidating my request saying file data not received. The request work with remaining form data (name, email etc). But when I send file along with file description this results in an error, that too only in RestSharp.

Comment: I'd suggest opening an issue. If you can also compare the multipart non-binary content generated by your code and what RestSharp produces, it would greatly help.

Comment: Sure will do and get back with results. Thanks for your hep.